# pm2 watch + Cluster Mode reload or restart?

Tags: pm2

If I'm on [Cluster Mode](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#reload) with `--watch`, when a file is updated, will pm2 automatically restart the app, or reload (0 downtime) the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will restart the app

No 0 downtime reload

From the doc :

> Note : Watching system does not provide any graceful action, pm2 kills and restarts your application without sending SIGINT

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/

Comment: The documentation no longer mentions this, but it's still the case.